# Add Missing Dates for Multiple Values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I seem to be having issues adding missing dates to a table - It is pretty straightforward if I am doing it for one individual item but the challenge comes when trying to add missing dates for multiple items. I do have a standard date table also.

This is a data sample I currently have...

| Date | Product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2022 | Item A | 2.74 |
| 2/1/2022 | Item B | 3.13 |
| 2/3/2022 | Item A | 2.82 |
| 2/3/2022 | Item B | 3.21 |
| 2/5/2022 | Item A | 2.77 |
| 2/5/2022 | Item B | 3.21 |

This is the expected solution...

| Date | Product | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2022 | Item A | 2.74 |
| 2/1/2022 | Item B | 3.13 |
| 2/2/2022 | Item A | NULL |
| 2/2/2022 | Item B | NULL |
| 2/3/2022 | Item A | 2.82 |
| 2/3/2022 | Item B | 3.21 |
| 2/4/2022 | Item A | NULL |
| 2/4/2022 | Item B | NULL |
| 2/5/2022 | Item A | 2.77 |
| 2/5/2022 | Item B | 3.26 |

Comment: You need a date table.

Comment: Apologies - I do have a standardized date table already in addition to the above first table.

Comment: If you have a date table and use that in the table, you should already see your desired end result. Make sure show items with no data is checked